# Infimum of an integral functional involving a symmetric matrix

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis, calculus-of-variations

I have a symmetric $d \times d$ matrix $A$ and I have the following functional:
$$
\mathcal J(h) := \int_{B_1(0)} \vert \langle Au,u \rangle\vert \frac{\vert h'(\vert u \vert)\vert}{\vert u \vert} du,
$$
where $B_1(0)$ is the unit ball in $\mathbb R^d$ and $h \in C_c^\infty(\mathbb R)$ with $\text{supp}\, h\subset [-1,1]$ and $\int h = 1$. Let me denote by $H$ the set of these functions $h$. I would like to find/estimate 
$$
\inf_{h \in H} \mathcal J(h).
$$

Do you have any ideas on how to approach this kind of problems? I have never heard nor read about such a problem. I have been playing with some toy models in $\mathbb R^2$ without success, I do not even manage to guess who is the infimum.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\newcommand{\al}{\alpha}
\newcommand{\de}{\delta}
\newcommand{\De}{\Delta}
\newcommand{\ep}{\varepsilon}
\newcommand{\ga}{\gamma}
\newcommand{\Ga}{\Gamma}
\newcommand{\la}{\lambda}
\newcommand{\Si}{\Sigma}
\newcommand{\thh}{\theta}
\newcommand{\om}{\omega}
\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb{R}}
\newcommand{\Z}{\mathbb{Z}}
\newcommand{\F}{\mathcal{F}}
\newcommand{\E}{\operatorname{\mathsf E}} 
\newcommand{\PP}{\operatorname{\mathsf P}}
\newcommand{\ii}[1]{\operatorname{\mathsf I}\{#1\}} 
\newcommand{\tf}{\widetilde{f}}$

The infimum is $0$ for $d\ge2$. Indeed, take any $h \in H$. For any real $\ep\in(0,1)$ and all real $r>0$, let $h_\ep(r):=\frac1\ep\,h(\frac r\ep)$, so that $h_\ep\in H$, $\text{supp}\,h_\ep\subset[-\ep,\ep]$, and
$$|h'_\ep(r)|=\frac1{\ep^2}\,\Big|h'\Big(\frac r\ep\Big)\Big|\le \frac M{\ep^2}$$
for some real $M>0$ and all real $r>0$, whence 
\begin{equation}
 0\le\mathcal J(h_\ep)
 \ll\int_0^\ep r^2\frac{|h'_\ep(r)|}{r}\,r^{d-1}\,dr
 \ll\int_0^\ep r^2\frac{1/\ep^2}{r}\,r^{d-1}\,dr
 \ll\ep^{d+1-2}\to0
\end{equation}
as $\ep\downarrow0$.

Comment: Oh nice, thanks for the useful answer! I admit I am a bit puzzled, as I expected the result to depend on the matrix $A$. However seems to be working, nice! Thanks again, +1!

Comment: I am glad to be able to help.

Comment: Sorry, there is still something not clear. It is easy to see that one can re-write the functional $\mathcal J$ as $\int \vert \langle Au, \nabla \tilde{h}(u) \rangle \vert du \ge \vert \int \langle Au, \nabla \tilde{h}(u) \rangle du \vert  = \vert \text{tr}\, A\vert$ since $\int u_i \partial_j \tilde{h}(u) du = \delta_{ij}$ (up to a sign, integration by parts). Where am I mistaken? Thanks again.

Comment: @Y.B. : What is $\tilde h$? Please also provide details on the rest of your comment.

Comment: Sorry for my confusion. So let me try to explain better. We have $J(h) = \int \vert \langle Au, \nabla h(\vert u \vert) \rangle \vert du$. Do you agree on this? Let me define a function $\tilde h$ so that $h(\vert u \vert) = \tilde h(u)$. Then $J(h) = \int \vert \langle Au, \nabla \tilde h(u) \rangle \vert du \ge \vert \int \langle Au, \nabla \tilde h(u) \rangle du \vert$. Am I right? This last guy, by definition, is the sum over i,j of $A_{ji} \cdot \int u_i \cdot \frac{\partial}{\partial u_j}\tilde h(u) du$. Do you agree? Now the last integral can be computed by integration by parts.

Comment: By integration by parts you see that  $\int u_i \frac{\partial}{\partial u_j} \tilde{h}(u) \, du$ is $\delta_{ij}$. Thus it seems to me that we have found a lower bound for $\mathcal J$, i.e. $\mathcal J \ge$ trace of $A$. I suspect I am wrong somewhere but do not see where. I apologize once again for the confusion and I thank for the help.

Comment: @Y.B. : It seems that at the last step you use $\int\tilde h(u)\,du=1$, which is not true in general (or ever).

Comment: Right, thanks for pointing it out. I am still confused a bit and I will think about it. Again thanks for helping.